# How to sort Vector<Vector<String>> on multiple elements keeping sub items grouped together?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, vector

So I am returning JSON data from a REST API where the data is already ordered by a date field and then is added to a Vector> which is used in a JTable. I need to group items with the same 5 digit key together and then order those by an additional identifier desc order (3,2,1) where date decides what 5 digit key is next.

For example:

```
[[28696, 2, 11/15/19 17:57]]
[[28696, 1, 11/15/19 17:56]]
[[00972, 2, 11/15/19 17:55]]
[[28696, 3, 11/15/19 17:54]]
[[00972, 1, 11/15/19 17:53]]
```

Should be

```
[[28696, 3, 11/15/19 17:54]]
[[28696, 2, 11/15/19 17:57]]
[[28696, 1, 11/15/19 17:56]]
[[00972, 2, 11/15/19 17:55]]
[[00972, 1, 11/15/19 17:53]]
```

See that 28696 is first one of the items in the group is the newest in the entire data set.

Comment: Make it a `Vector<MyClassThatHoldsThisDataProperly>` and create a sort function for `MyClassThatHoldsThisDataProperly`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not doable with a single `sort` operation. Instead you can use streams to meet your requirements of grouping, sorting the groups, and sorting the data within the groups.

First note that I converted your `List<List<String>>` into a `List<Data>` (as recommended by Max Vollmer) to make this easier to work with and understand. If you really need it as a `List` you can replace `Data` with `List<String>` and the `Data.get??()` with `List.get(?)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    List<Data> list = Arrays.asList( //
            new Data("28696", "2", "11/15/19 17:57"), //
            new Data("28696", "1", "11/15/19 17:56"), //
            new Data("00972", "2", "11/15/19 17:55"), //
            new Data("28696", "3", "11/15/19 17:54"), //
            new Data("00972", "1", "11/15/19 17:53"));

    Comparator<Data> sortByTimestamp = Comparator.comparing(Data::getTimestamp).reversed();
    Comparator<Data> sortByOccurrence = Comparator.comparing(Data::getOccurrence).reversed();

    // LinkedHashMap keeps the insertion order
    Collector<Data, ?, LinkedHashMap<String, List<Data>>> groupByIdKeepInsertOrder
            = Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList());

    List<Data> result = list.stream()
            .sorted(sortByTimestamp) // sort all data by timestamp, if it's already sorted by timestamp you can skip this
            .collect(groupByIdKeepInsertOrder) // group them by id keeping the timestamp order
            .values().stream() // stream the lists of data grouped together
            .peek(l -> l.sort(sortByOccurrence)) // sort each list of data by occurrence
            .flatMap(Collection::stream) // flatten the lists into a single stream
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect all Data into a single list

    System.out.println(result);
    // [[28696, 3, 11/15/19 17:54],
    //  [28696, 2, 11/15/19 17:57],
    //  [28696, 1, 11/15/19 17:56],
    //  [00972, 2, 11/15/19 17:55],
    //  [00972, 1, 11/15/19 17:53]]
}
```

---

```
private static class Data {
    private final String id;
    private final String occurrence;
    private final String timestamp;

    public Data(String id, String occurrence, String timestamp) {
        this.id = id;
        this.occurrence = occurrence;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public String getOccurrence() { return occurrence; }
    public String getTimestamp() { return timestamp; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "[" + id + ", " + occurrence + ", " + timestamp + "]";}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as needed. Thanks for the detailed code and explanation.